# In Excel, is it possible to use conditional formatting to always highlight TODAY's date?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

In column A I have dates going from May 1, 2012 to May 1, 2013.  Row 1 has May 1st, Row 2 has May 2nd, Row 3 has May 3rd, and so forth.

Is it possible to highlight JUST TODAY's date?  That way when I open up my spreadsheet I can see what row I should be looking at.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highlight your dates in column A, go to Conditional Formatting and add the following condition:

```
[Cell Value Is] [equal to]  =TODAY()
```

Comment: this worked! thanks for the super fast reply.  i have to wait 2 minutes before i'm allowed to accept this as the answer